# Can I create a direct link in Box?

Tags: box.com

My workplace provides a corporate box.com account. Using this I can create links to files, but they don't link directly to the file - they link to a box.com webpage which shows a preview of the file.

This is no use for my current need, because I want to share something that the recipient will download from a linux command line with `wget`, and if they do that at present they end up with a local copy of the box.com web page instead.

Is there any way to create/share a direct link using box.com as it exists in 2020? Googling reveals something called a "Direct link" in the Box help pages, but it is marked as deprecated, being from the "old Box experience".